# Firebase Realtime Database Insecure Rule Warning

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I keep getting emails saying my database is not secure after implementing my security rules. The emails specify that any authenticated user can read/write to my database but I implemented specific access rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
      ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
      ".write": "auth.uid !== null && newData.hasChildren(['score', 'quote', 
        'description', 'source', 'sourceType', 'ownerID', 'ownerImageURl', 'ownerUsername', 'timestamp', 'usersVoted'])",
      ".indexOn":["sourceType", "ownerID"],
      "$postID": {
        ".write": "!data.hasChild('ownerID')",
        "score": {
          ".write": "newData.isNumber() && (newData.val() === data.val() + 1 || newData.val() === data.val() - 1) && !root.child('posts').child('$postID').child('usersVoted').hasChild(auth.uid)"
        },
        "usersVoted": {
          ".write": "!data.hasChild(auth.uid)",
            "$userID": {
              ".write": false
            }
        }
      } 
    },
    "users": {
      ".write":"auth.uid !== null && !data.hasChild(auth.uid)",
      "$userID": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $userID",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $userID"
      }
    },
    "comments": {
      ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
      "$postID": {
        ".write": "auth.uid !== null",
        "$commentID": {
            ".write": false  
        }
      }
    }
    
  }
}
```

Why does Firebase think that any user can read/write to any location in my database?

EDIT: I haven't gotten the email in a while so I think my rules are secure.

Answer (score 1):

For example this rule for `users` node, is not secure:

```
"users": {
  ".write":"auth.uid !== null && !data.hasChild(auth.uid)",
  "$userID": {
    ".read": "auth.uid === $userID",
    ".write": "auth.uid === $userID"
  }
}
```

Because, this rule allows any authenticated user and non-existing user to write to your users node (not secure):

```
  ".write":"auth.uid !== null && !data.hasChild(auth.uid)",
```

and it overwrites this rule (as if this is meaningless now):

```
  ".write": "auth.uid === $userID"
```

To make it secure, `users` rule must look like this:

```
"users": {

  "$userID": {
    ".write":"auth.uid !== null && !data.hasChild(auth.uid) && auth.uid === $userID",
    ".read": "auth.uid === $userID"
  }
}
```

**So fix your rules, and be careful of RULES CASCADING.**

Comment: Once a user is authenticated they get added to the `users` node with their ID which stops people who are authenticated and are not added to the node from overwriting other users' data. The rule you suggest doesn't allow me to add new users to the `users` node.

Comment: remove this then `!data.hasChild(auth.uid)`